# Using a button as a boolean switch

Tags: android-layout, button

I'm trying to make a button in android function as a boolean switch. I want it to do something on the first click and do something else on the second click. On the third click, I want it to do the same thing on the first click et cetera. The main reason I want this due to the text element on the button that changes with each click. Switches and checkboxes have no texts to change.

I've tried finding documentations on doing this online but can't seem to find any previous examples of doing this. Would appreciate if anyone has any ideas or just tell me outright that this is not workable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourButton
    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private boolean state = false;
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if ( state ) { 
                state = false;
                yourButton.setText("False");
            } else {
                state = true;
                yourButton.setText("True");
            }

        }
     });
```

You can try something like this, by the way i DIDN'T test this code i'm just trying to show you a way you could try to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. set button to change drawable background and remove 
 button.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
private boolean state=false;
 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
 if (state){
       state=false;
 textView.setBackground ( getDrawable(R.drawable.led_mode ) );
}
else{
state=true;
textview.setbackground(null);
}
}
});
```